# SQL When a result has two rows of output, how can I sum them?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query below:

```
Select
count(CDT) as Actions
From Player_Tapjoy
Where
Trunc(CDT) >= To_Date('2012-sep-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
And Trunc(CDT) < To_Date('2012-sep-12','yyyy-mon-dd')
Union All
Select 
Count(CDT) As Actions
From Player_aux_pt
Where
Site = 'AppCircle' And
Trunc(CDT) >= To_Date('2012-sep-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
And Trunc(CDT) < To_Date('2012-sep-12','yyyy-mon-dd')
```

This output gives me two rows, one for each of the select functions. How can I combine these to get the sum of the two select functions? And on top of that, how do I group it by CDT (the date)?

Comment: Do you want the sum on each row or do you want the sum on a separate row?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just want the sum of the two rows, so the query result would only have one row instead of two(the combination of the two original rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this, with the grouping by date:

```
select cdt, sum(actions) as actions_sum
    from (  select trunc(cdt) as cdt, count(cdt) as actions
              from player_tapjoy
             where trunc(cdt) >= to_date('2012-sep-01', 'yyyy-mon-dd') and
                   trunc(cdt) < to_date('2012-sep-12', 'yyyy-mon-dd')
          group by trunc(cdt)
          union all
            select trunc(cdt) as cdt, count(cdt) as actions
              from player_aux_pt
             where site = 'AppCircle' and
                   trunc(cdt) >= to_date('2012-sep-01', 'yyyy-mon-dd') and
                   trunc(cdt) < to_date('2012-sep-12', 'yyyy-mon-dd')
          group by trunc(cdt))
group by cdt
```